# Ontology Representation of this sentence

Tags: ontology, protege

I have a problem in Protege to represent this sentence in ontology protege

"DeveloperCSharp is an Engineer who is expert in C# not in Java and Python" [My ontology image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwdR8.png)

Comment: And what is that problem exactly?

Comment: My problem is how to add the relation and what is the restriction should I follow.